# ejs <%- body %> not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am going to use a default template called layout.ejs, and this is the code in the file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%- body %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i am trying to bind this file with my new.ejs, that is inside my event folder:

```
<% if (parseInt(page['prevPage'].charAt(0)) === 0) { %>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/admin/bookings/<%= page.nextPage %>">Próximo &gt;</a>
<% } else { %>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/admin/bookings/<%= page.prevPage %>">&lt; Anterior</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/admin/bookings/<%= page.nextPage %>">Próximo &gt;</a>
<% } %>
```

The templating engine is not working, is not binding the two files. i need some extra configuration in express to do that?

I am using express 4.*

Thanks.

Comment: Did you put : app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); in your express configuration ?

Comment: yes @Ricoxor, my app is in the last step of development, i just need configure the layout templating now

Comment: Please paste more code ! I can't help you :/ What do you want to display in body ? https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a monkey patch I've used in the past to use layouts with ejs in Express 4:

```
/*
   Usage:
     Set a global/default layout with:
        app.set('view layout', 'foo');
     Set a layout per-render (overrides global layout) with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: 'bar' });
     Or disable a layout if a global layout is set with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: false });
     If no layout is provided using either of the above methods,
     then the view will be rendered as-is like normal.

     Inside your layout, the variable `body` holds the rendered partial/child view.

   Installation:
     Call `mpResponse();` before doing `require('express');` in your application.
*/

function mpResponse() {
  var expressResponse = require('express/lib/response'),
      expressResRender = expressResponse.render;
  expressResponse.render = function(view, options, fn) {
    options = options || {};
    var self = this,
        req = this.req,
        app = req.app,
        layout,
        cb;

    // support callback function as second arg
    if (typeof options === 'function')
      fn = options, options = {};

    // merge res.locals
    options._locals = self.locals;

    // default callback to respond
    fn = fn || function(err, str) {
      if (err) return req.next(err);
      self.send(str);
    };

    if (typeof options.layout === 'string')
      layout = options.layout;
    else if (options.layout !== false
             && typeof app.get('view layout') === 'string')
      layout = app.get('view layout');

    if (layout) {
      cb = function(err, str) {
        if (err) return req.next(err);
        options.body = str;
        expressResRender.call(self, layout, options, fn);
      };
    } else
      cb = fn;

    // render
    app.render(view, options, cb);
  };
}
```

Comment: Express doesn't explicitly support it, but some template engines support it themselves (not ejs though) and may look for the `layout` and other such view variables.

Answer (score 2):

express 4.x do not support layouts, you can use module "express-ejs-layouts" to solve this problem

```js
npm install express-ejs-layouts
```

in you code, please contain:

```js
var expressLayouts=require("express-ejs-layouts");
app.use(expressLayouts);
```